# Выделение всех чекбоксов таблицы

Tags: html, jquery, checkbox

Есть таблица в которой в одной из колонок стоят чекбоксы для выбора строки

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-checks">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <div id="all" class="checker">
                    <span>
                        <input id="all" class="styled" type="checkbox" name="checkRow" style="opacity: 0;">
                    </span>
                </div>
            </th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Автар</th>
            <th>Название</th>
            <th>URL</th>
            <th>Дата создания</th>
            <th>Статус</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach($latest_materials as $item): ?>
        <tr data-id="<?=$item['material_id']?>">
            <td>
                <div id="" class="checker">
                    <span>
                        <input class="styled" type="checkbox" name="checkRow" style="opacity: 0;">
                    </span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?=$item[ 'material_id']?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?=$item[ 'author']?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?=$item[ 'title']?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?=$item[ 'material_id']?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?=$item[ 'date']?>
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

когда выбираешь одну строку или несколько рисуется галочка, с помощью jquery добавляться класс `.checked { background-position: -17px 0px;}`

```
$(document).on('click','input:checkbox',function(e) {
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $tr = $(this).parents('span');
        $tr.addClass('checked'); 
    } else {
        $tr = $(this).parents('span');
        $tr.removeClass('checked'); 
        }
```

Но я не могу добиться когда нажимаешь на чекбокс в шапке таблицы, чтоб добавлялся класс checked во все span таблицы. И я не уверен что и этот код jquery написал правильно хотя он и работает.

Answer (score 4):

Задачу можно решить так: (upd)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var table = $('table.table-checks');
    table
    .on('change', '> tbody input:checkbox',function() {
        $(this).closest('span').toggleClass('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
    })
    .on('change', '#all', function(){
        $('> tbody input:checkbox', table).prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked')).trigger('change');
    });
});
```

вот пример http://jsfiddle.net/3AEQf/7/

Comment: а есть другие варианты, у меня firefox завис от этого кода

Comment: Вы могли свой код модифицировать.... чтоб при клике на выделить все можно было и снять все! И сам чекбокс тоже чтоб был выделен, а у вас кнопка.

Comment: я мог бы. а вы пробовали?

Comment: [Такой вариант][1] сойдёт?

   [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/3AEQf/5/

Comment: @Deonis, думаю нет. так как 1) в его таблице есть ещё и другие чекбоксы, по этому у меня более подробное условие выборки элементов; 2) в вопросе при клике на чекбокс запускается обработчик события, по этому я использовал trigger.

Comment: @kolpak,  попробовал получилось такое 
http://jsfiddle.net/3AEQf/6/
правильно? Я jquery не знаю, методом научного тыка делаю....

Comment: не правильно.
правильно как-то так http://jsfiddle.net/3AEQf/7/
и вот эта ссылка для получасового ознакомления learn.javascript.ru/#book-toc-767

Answer (score 1):

Лови друган решение своей задачи, просто вставь в свой HTML и увидишь что всё работает. По аналогии сопоставь со своим кодом. Добра тебе

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>JavaScript уроки</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        $("#selall").click(function () {
            if (!$("#selall").is(":checked")){
                $(".checkbox").removeAttr("checked");
            }
            else{
                $(".checkbox").prop("checked","checked");

            }
        });

    });
</script>
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="selall"> Выделить всё</label>  <br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="checks" class="checkbox" value="1"> Чекбокс 1</label>  <br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="checks" class="checkbox" value="2"> Чекбокс 2</label>  <br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="checks" class="checkbox" value="3"> Чекбокс 3</label>

</body> 
</html>
```